# Best way to get layout inflater?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have just come across the `getLayoutInflater()` method, I have always used 
`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` to get the layout inflater so I was just wondering what is the difference between these two? Is there a case where one of these will work and not the other ? Thanks

Comment: hmm why the downvote ? Is a legit question...

Comment: Probably lack of research. Did you Google this? It's certainly been asked before.

Comment: @MikeM.  believe you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an `Activity`, both of those should give you the same `LayoutInflater`, but I would assume `getLayoutInflater()` is better because it simply grabs the `LayoutInflater` that is already cached in the `Window` given to the `Activity`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the caching of the layout inflater, so performance wise `getLayoutInflater()` is better to use?

Comment: @Amroelaswar Possibly, I haven't measured this. It is however much easier to read and makes the code look cleaner.